# Money amount regex

Tags: regex

So, I am trying to make a regulat expression for the a money amount:

This is what I've done so far:

```
((\d*)([,]{1})(\d{3})([,]{1})?(\d{3})?)|((\d*)([.]{1})(\d{3})([.]{1})?(\d{3})?)|(\d{1,3})
```

The expressions that needs to validate are, for example:

1
11
111
1.115
11.234
111.111
1,111
11,234
111,111
1111111111,123123123
123.123
123
111.222.333
111,222,333

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

For example, now it valiates 1,,,,,2 or 333....4 or 12312asdasd and it's not right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole regex inside a non-capturing group and then use anchors.

```
^(?:((\d*)([,]{1})(\d{3})([,]{1})?(\d{3})?)|((\d*)([.]{1})(\d{3})([.]{1})?(\d{3})?)|(\d{1,3}))$
```